# Simple(st) Datomic test program hangs at exit

Tags: clojure, datomic

The following program, when run from an überjar, exits at the end only when using the in-memory Datomic database; when connecting to the Datomic server, it hangs indefinitely rather than exiting the JVM:

```
(ns myns.example
  (:use [datomic.api :only [db q] :as d])
  (:gen-class))

;; WORKS: (def uri "datomic:mem://testdb")

(def uri "datomic:free://localhost:4334/testdb2")

(defn -main []
  (println 1)
  (when (d/create-database uri)
    (d/connect uri))
  (shutdown-agents)
  (println 2))
```

Run as:

```
lein uberjar && java -cp target/myns-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar myns.example
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
```

and hangs.  It only hangs if the DB doesn't exist when the program starts.

Anyone know why, or how to fix?  This is with both `datomic-free-0.8.4020.26` and `datomic-free-0.8.3941`.

**UPDATE** -- the above program does actually terminate, but it takes a very long time (> 1 minute).  I'd like to know why.

Comment: Have you tried to `(d/release conn)`?

Comment: Tried that with no apparent difference -- but I learned in the process that the program above does eventually terminate, it just takes over a minute (!!!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shutdown-agents` takes up to one minute to complete (assuming no agents are running an action).

This is due to the way `java.util.concurrent` cached thread pools work.

Comment: Thanks!  The program takes a minute or so to complete regardless of whether I bother with `shutdown-agents`.  Any idea why?

Comment: I guess Datomic is invoking it? Did it not, then the program would hang forever...

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking this as the accepted answer given the fact that the 1 minute timescale matches, despite the fact that I don't understand how the shutdown occurred when I removed `shutdown-agents`.

Comment: I could be entirely wrong though - and the timing be just a coincidence. Try sleeping for 30 seconds, then sending an agent to println some value. If it succeeds, then shutdown-agents is not involved.

Answer (score 0):

Use [datomic.api/shutdown](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/index.html#datomic.api/shutdown)

> ## shutdown
>
> *function*
>
> Usage: (shutdown shutdown-clojure)
>
> Shut down all peer
>   resources.  This method should be called as part of clean shutdown of
>   a JVM process.  Will release all Connections, and, if shutdown-clojure
>   is true, will release Clojure resources. Programs written in Clojure
>   can set shutdown-clojure to false if they manage Clojure resources
>   (e.g. agents) outside of Datomic; programs written in other JVM
>   languages should typically set shutdown-clojure to true.
>
> *Added in Datomic Clojure version 0.8.3861*

```
(ns myns.example
  (:require [datomic.api :as d])
  (:gen-class))

(def uri "datomic:free://localhost:4334/testdb2")

(defn -main []
  (d/create-database uri)
  (let [conn (d/connect uri)]
    (try
      ;; do something
      (finally (d/shutdown true)))
```